# Update all documents adding new fields with different values

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, uuid

I'm using uuid package in express app now I need add those ids to all my document.

```
Users.updateMany({},{$set:{newId:uuid()}},(err,success)=>{
      if(success) console.log(success);
});
```

I tried this way,success returns with different values,but in database it saves with same value.I need to add that newId field in my documents with different ids thats all.Thanks for attention and for help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with async/await this should work

```
async function updateUuid() {
  try {
    const users = await Users.find({});
    for (const user of users) {
      const uuid = uuid();
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, { $set: { newId: uuid } });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not yet, As I see its great thing.I've tried to find functions in mongodb to do this,but I couldn't .So I think this is the best way.Thank you anttud.

Answer (score 0):

A little late bit found out that using forEach and a function solves the issue with generating same value. Executed below in mongo workspace

```
function generateRandomString(length) {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@+_-=';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result
};

db.users2.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    const data = {
        ...doc,
        uuid: generateRandomString(30)
    }
    db.users.insert(data);
});
```